# externally create jaxb annotations for class

Tags: web-services, annotations, jaxb, jax-ws, cxf

So, usually I apply JAXB annotations in the code as follows:

```
package com.example;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Foo", namespace = "example.com")
@XmlType(name = "Foo", namespace = "example.com")
public class Foo {
    ...
}
```

Foo is a java class that is used to communicate with web services (via Spring/CXF). The above annotations, help generate the XML Schema in the wsdl appropriately.

I have hit a situation where I can not modify the class itself, but I can provide an jaxb external binding file to the code that generates the schema. Note that the @XmlRootElement exists in the class.

How do I write an equivalent binding file that does what the above annotations do?

Answer (score 7):

If you just need to add `@XmlType(name = "Foo", namespace = "example.com")` annotation to the generated class you can use JAXB Annotate Plugin.

If you're using CXF and maven you can also you cxf-codegen-plugin somehow like this

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${service.src.dir}</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>service.wsdl</wsdl>
                        <extraargs>
                            <extraarg>-xjc-Xannotate</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-b</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>${wsdl.dir}/bindings.xjb</extraarg>
                        </extraargs>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb.commons.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>                
</plugin>
```

You can also use maven-jaxb2-plugin:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${maven-jaxb2.version}</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>process-xsd</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <configuration>
            <schemaIncludes>
                <include>**/*.xsd</include>
            </schemaIncludes>
            <bindingIncludes>
                <include>**/*.xjb</include>
            </bindingIncludes>
            <generateDirectory>${jaxb.src.dir}</generateDirectory>
            <extension>true</extension>
            <args>
                <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
            </args>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                    <version>${jaxb.commons.version}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Here is sample binding file:

```
<jaxb:bindings
xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
version="2.0">

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='Foo']">
            <annox:annotate target="class">
                <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType" name="Foo" namespace = "example.com"/>
            </annox:annotate>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>

</jaxb:bindings>
```

If you need to modify `@XmlRootElement` too, just add another one `annox:annotate` element:

```
<annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement" name="Foo" namespace = "example.com"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

The MOXy implementation of JAXB has an external mapping file that you can use to provide the metadata.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="com.example">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="Customer">
            <xml-type name="Foo" namespace="example.com"/>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/extending-jaxb-representing-annotations.html

Comment: any way to do this using the standard jaxb binding file?

Comment: The standard JAXB binding file is used to control how the classes are generated from an XML schema.  If I understand your use case directly you are starting with Java classes and want to generate and XML schema?

Comment: Yep - in my case CXF generates the XML schema in the WSDL and I need a way to control the schema.