# I would like to add @XmlRoot annotation on CXF codegen

Tags: java, jaxb, cxf, cxf-codegen-plugin

I have a WSDL file which contains the following entry:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="urn:CP_Ablakido" xmlns:s0="urn:CP_Ablakido" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:CP_Ablakido">
      <xsd:element name="GetList_11" type="s0:InputMapping1"/>
      <xsd:complexType name="InputMapping1">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="Qualification" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element name="startRecord" type="xsd:string"/>
          <xsd:element name="maxLimit" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:element name="GetList_11Response" type="s0:OutputMapping1"/>
      <xsd:complexType name="OutputMapping1">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="getListValues">
            <xsd:complexType>....
```

I use the CXF Codegen plugin with the following settings:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/wsdl2java</sourceRoot>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And the generated java code look like:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "OutputMapping1", propOrder = {
    "getListValues"
})
public class OutputMapping1 {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected List<OutputMapping1 .GetListValues> getListValues;
```

The problem is that the @XmlRootElement is missing from here. There was another similar questions like

1. [maven-cxf-codegen-plugin using Jaxb binding to add inheritance for all generated classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23961421/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-using-jaxb-binding-to-add-inheritance-for-all-generated)
2. [Annotating CXF (wsdl2java) generated package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894811/annotating-cxf-wsdl2java-generated-package)
3. [externally create jaxb annotations for class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143323/externally-create-jaxb-annotations-for-class)

As the other answers mentioned that I can put bindings file. 
So I created a binding file with the following content:

```
<jaxb:bindings
xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
version="2.0">
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xsd:element[@name='GetList_11Response']">
            <annox:annotate target="class">
                <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement" name="GetList_11Response"/>
          </annox:annotate>
        </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

And I've added the following block to POM.XML:

```
<wsdlOptions>
    <wsdlOption>
        <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/CP_Ablakido_1.wsdl</wsdl>
        <bindingFiles>                                       
            <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/CP_Ablakido_1.xjb
            </bindingFile>
        </bindingFiles>
    </wsdlOption>
</wsdlOptions>
```

After that I've got error message:

```
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; systemId: file:/Project/icp-integration/icpiCameI/src/main/resources/wsdl/CP_Ablakido_1.xjb; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 72; XPath evaluation of "//xs:element[@name='GetList_11Response']" results in empty target node
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.reportError(Internalizer.java:624)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.reportError(Internalizer.java:618)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.buildTargetNodeMap(Internalizer.java:294)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.buildTargetNodeMap(Internalizer.java:390)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.Internalizer.transform(Internalizer.java:146)
```

So I don't know how exactly can I describe that when the complexType is OutputMapping1 then put  @XmlRootElement in OutputMapping1.java with the name of "GetList_11Response".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the solution. It was trickey, because:

1. Have to handle that the XSD is inlined in WSDL. (The trick is schemaLocation="CP_Ablakido_1.wsdl#types1". It tells the JAXB that use  node in WSDL file.)
2. Have to configure CXF to use XJC plugin (annox).

Have to add the following fragments to POM.XML:

```
<wsdlOption>
    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/CP_Ablakido_1.wsdl</wsdl>
    <bindingFiles>
        <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/CP_Ablakido_1.xjb</bindingFile> 
    </bindingFiles>
    <extraargs><extraarg>-xjc-Xannotate</extraarg></extraargs>
</wsdlOption>
```

and dependencies have to add to plugin:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.0</version>
</dependency>   

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf.xjcplugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-xjc-ts</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

The XJB file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings version="2.0" 
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="annox xjc"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
    xmlns:inheritance="http://jaxb2-commons.dev.java.net/basic/inheritance">

  <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="CP_Ablakido_1.wsdl#types1" node="/xs:schema"> 
       <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='InputMapping1']">
            <annox:annotate target="class">
                <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement" name="GetList_11"/>
          </annox:annotate>
      </jaxb:bindings>    
      <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='OutputMapping1']">
            <annox:annotate target="class">
                <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement" name="GetList_11Response"/>
          </annox:annotate>
      </jaxb:bindings>
   </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Comment: Dear Robert, could you please post version of the CXF you have used? I am trying to replicate your solution but no luck so far. Thank you.

Comment: Hello Miso! 3.0.5 of the CXF I used. I think have to work with newer version too. Are you sure all the steps followed in the question too? Is the wsdlOption fragment added to cxf-codegen ?

Comment: This just for ONE type  in the WSDL, isn't it? What, if I want to let JAXB2 annotate ALL (GetList_11) maybe 10 or 50 or 100...) types in a WSDL file with the XmlRootAnnotation?

Comment: You are right, but I haven't found better solution. :(

Answer (score 0):

@du-it As I understand, you don't want to apply XmlRootElement to all of the classes automatically. 
This is the reason:
https://community.oracle.com/blogs/kohsuke/2006/03/03/why-does-jaxb-put-xmlrootelement-sometimes-not-always
Therefore, doing it for each type separately is the proper way to do it.

Comment: The link is dead